# How to make sure that stuff in the SafeArea is above all other widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am building a webapp that needs to be able to view 360 degree images, but when i load one to cover the whole screen it ends up over the safe area.

[360 image covering some of the safe area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha41G.jpg)

[Portrait mode, easier to see problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kZlu.png)

I essentially want the navigation bar to "cover" the jagged corners of the image instead of them being above. Something like being able to change the Z-index of both the safe area and the page independently would be great.

Below is some code

[code for safearea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whWnd.png)

[page containing the 360 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYz4R.png)

Have tried to find several libraries with Z-index.
One i've tried is stack, but stack requires both of them to exist in the stack, could this work, and if so how?

--

decided to extend the body to the entire page and just have a drawer in an AppBar

[Image of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FzvF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('SafeArea Demo'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          // This will ensure that SafeArea is above all other widgets
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // Your content widgets here
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bro need to put SafeArea after using Scafford, try it

Answer (score 0):

decided to extend the body to the entire page and just have a drawer in an AppBar
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FzvF.png

Comment: You should not provide code as a screenshot, instead use markdown and wrap the code in codeblocks